# working directory with spaces in R

Tags: r

I am having the problem that when I use `setwd()` with a path that includes spaces (e.g. `setwd("C:/Users/Name/My Documents/")` I get the error message

> "cannot change working directory"

I am a bit suprised that I did not find much about this here or on google - so it must either be a rare error or everyone knows about it I reckon. Either way, is there a why to work around it?

I am using Windows 7 and R version 3.0.2.

Comment: Try `setwd("C:/Users/Name/My\\ Documents/")` or `setwd("\"C:/Users/Name/My Documents\"/")`, might work.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately neither of those are working - same error.

Comment: Have you tried with a different directory (that includes spaces). I can't reproduce this. Are you sure the directory exists (i.e. have you checked with Windows Explorer)?

Comment: Hmm, `setwd("C:/Users/Name/Desktop/New Folder")` works fine, so I really don't understand what's going on.. `setwd("C:/Users/Name/")` works, `setwd("C:/Users/Name/My Documents")` does not, but in the Explorer I can see the folder so it's definitely there.

Comment: OK, I got it, "My Documents" was set to "read-only", no idea how that happened..

Comment: I don't think My documents is actually My Documents.  Just for giggles try this: `setwd("C:/Users/Name/Documents")` as you say you're Win 7: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Documents

Answer (score 4):

R cannot setwd into a directory that it doesn't have 'x' (execute) permission for.

Comment: Worth knowing, and worth being explicit about it in this question.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, but if really needed, you can use the function `shortPathName`.

```
> shortPathName("C:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/")
[1] "C:\\PROGRA~2\\Adobe\\"
```

Answer (score 1):

I can replicate your error if I just copy and paste

```
setwd("C:/Users/Name/My Documents/")
```

to console as is. The problem is that R cannot find the specified path. I believe that you should replace "Name" with your username...

If I replace "Name" with my username, it works as expected.

Comment: thanks, but I replaced my username with "name" on purpose for privacy reasons ;)

Comment: I thought so at first, but since nothing that was suggested worked for you, I posted the answer. I see now that you had the read-only issue.