# Re-setting HOME directory in R

Tags: r, directory

I'm having an issue running some packages (including `rmarkdown`) in R. The problem is because I'm using Windows 10 and my `HOME` directory path includes spaces:

`C:/Users/My Name/Documents`

From doing a bit of research I realise that I need to change my `HOME` directory to something that doesn't have spaces; this is explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732049/change-home-directory-for-r), but not specifically how one should go about doing it.

I have two questions about this problem:

1. How do I change the `HOME` directory to a path with no spaces?
2. Will this cause issues when running other scripts, and if so is there a particular location on my `C:` drive that would be best to relocate `HOME` to?

An answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016907/setting-the-home-directory-in-windows-r) suggests I should use `Sys.setenv(R_USER="/my/desired/path")`: would this force R to use a different `HOME` path? And if so, would I need to run this before running every script?

Edit: someone suggested looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738564/r-set-environment-variable-permanently), but this doesn't quite get me where I want to be because I want to change the directory; so, re-setting the environment variable (by adding the `.Renviron` file to `HOME`) surely wouldn't work?

Many thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - Set environment variable permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49738564/r-set-environment-variable-permanently)

Comment: rmarkdown should *not* have issues with spaces in the home directory (in fact, there’s no reason for *any* package to have issues with this — it’s incredibly sloppy programming).

Comment: This issue shows up every now and then (it doesn't stop me using markdown altogether) when I try to install certain packages for use in markdown, so it might not be rmarkdown itself. This time I've tried to run `devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')` and it won't work.

Comment: @CatherineLaing Are you sure you’re not misdiagnosing the issue? TinyTeX should work with spaces in path names. Why do you think spaces in the `HOME` path are the cause of the problems?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Whatever the problem is, it won't let me run TinyTeX - I get:

`Downloading GitHub repo yihui/tinytex@master
    ERROR
   cannot change to directory 'C:\Users\My'
   The system cannot find the path specified.
Error in run(bin, args = real_cmdargs, stdout_line_callback = real_callback(stdout),  : 
  System command error`

So as far as I can tell the problem lies in the path name of my `HOME` folder?

Comment: Use [shortPathName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23603074/working-directory-with-spaces-in-r/42528950#42528950) to get the path without spaces.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I don’t see how this would help here.

Comment: @KonradRudolph To set the path to install the package. `install.packages` does not work when there are white spaces in the path.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Huh. Is that a fact? That’s a pretty bad bug in R that should be fixed, shouldn’t it? Anyway, I’m assuming you’d then do `.libPaths(shortPathName(.libPaths()[1L]))`?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes this a fact. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52022233/install-packages-does-not-deal-with-whitespace-in-file-path or https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1467 I agree this should be fixed.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm using `install_github`; is there a way to specify the path with this?

Comment: @CatherineLaing Yes. Try `install_github(......, lib = shortPathName(.libPaths()[1]))`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Ah no that doesn't work - I get exactly the same error as above.

Comment: @CatherineLaing Looks like the problem is the folder for the download. Normally this is a temporary directory. Why do you get when you do `tempdir()` ? Are there white spaces ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent No white spaces there: `"C:\\Users\\NAME~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\RtmpWcbIH0"`